# Product collection and filter Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom attribute called groupId and I have about 1000 products and they all have groups of 4 products sharing the same groupId .

Now I have a category I want to display these products in but I only want to show one of the 4 products from each group.

So I thought that I can filter this and match a collection against the products in the category and insert them if there is no match and so on . 
But the collection loads all products once so if I loop through the collection it won't notis the product that was inputed during that run .

Is there some one that has a suggestion to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's `DISTINCT` to be sure to have one product from each group.

```
$collection->getSelect()->distinct($groupId);
```